# Data Driven SSRS Subscription using the XML-Based Query Language for SharePoint List Connections

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that uses the SharePoint List data connection. It works just fine using the query below. I want a Data Driven Subscription to email the report to the user whose email address shows in the report. The problem is that a user can show up multiple times in the same run of the report and SSRS seems to want to send them an email for each time their email address shows up. I used to do this all the time with reports that used standard t-SQL using Select Distinct but this xml based query language doesnt seem to have such a function.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to either get SSRS to be smart enough to send only one email per person OR get a variation on this query to only return each email address once?

Thanks

```
<RSSharePointList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ListName>SSRS_Subscriptions</ListName>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="Title" />
    <FieldRef Name="count" />
    <FieldRef Name="eMail" />
    <FieldRef Name="Org" />
  </ViewFields>
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <Gt>
        <FieldRef Name="count" />
        <Value Type="Number">0</Value>
      </Gt>
    </Where>
  </Query>
</RSSharePointList>
```

Comment: You mentioned, you used to do Distinict in T-SQL. Can you not apply Distinct in XML.
I come from Dynamics CRM Development side and we all the Time use Fetchxml where in Distinct clause is Provided.
Link for Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/use-fetchxml-construct-query

Comment: This is, apparently a different form of xml based query language. I’m pretty sure this is caml.